# Upper bound of $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j-1}{n+1 \choose j}{n \choose i}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to find max (or sup.) of the sum: $$S=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j-1}{n+1 \choose j}{n \choose i}.$$
I found  $S\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.2(n+1).4^n$ but It seems it's not correct.
(I used this formular :$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j-1}{n \choose i}\le 2j {n \choose j-1}$, is it true?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the decomposition $${n+1\choose j}={n\choose j}+{n\choose j-1},$$ and the change of variable $j\to j-1$ in the second sum that this decomposition yields, one gets $$S=\sum_{i\lt j}{n+1\choose j}{n\choose i}=\sum_{i\lt j}{n\choose j}{n\choose i}+\sum_{i\leqslant j}{n\choose j}{n\choose i}.$$
By symmetry, the last sum on the RHS is $$\sum_{i\leqslant j}{n\choose j}{n\choose i}=\sum_{i\geqslant j}{n\choose j}{n\choose i},$$ hence $$S=\sum_{i,j}{n\choose j}{n\choose i}=\left(\sum_{i}{n\choose i}\right)^2=4^n.$$

Comment: Thank you so much Did.
In fact, I would like to find out upper bound of this formular where a,b are constant:
$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j-1} {\frac{a}{b}}^{j+i} {\frac{b-a}{b-j-i} }^{2n+1-j-i} {n+1 \choose j}{n \choose i}$.
This is new problem

Comment: Sorry but $4^n$ is a perfect upper bound, no? (Unrelated: I see no $a$, $b$ in the question.)

Comment: Sorry to edit again.
I would like to find out upper bound of this formula where a,b are constant:
$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{j-1} ({\frac{a}{b}})^{j+i} ({\frac{b-a}{b-j-i} })^{2n+1-j-i} {n+1 \choose j}{n \choose i}$.
This is a new problem

Comment: "This is a new problem." Hence a new question.

Comment: yes, I will ask a new question in the list